# Is there a way to display the feature maps in the Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

There are many images that show the extracted features of an image that is processed with a Neural Network, like this one:

[image]

Is there a way to display these Images with the Tensorflow Object Detection API? I want to use them for a report and I find it interesting to see the features that are really relevant for my model to detect objects in my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with a little bit of work, there are no tools to do this out of the box. The object detection API uses the classification networks as a base and builds on it. You should be able to save any intermediate tensor and visualize it.